# How to convert a JsonObject into an Avro Generic Record?

Tags: java, json, kotlin, apache-beam, avro

I'm still a newbie in this area, and currently I'm trying to deserialise data from a parquet file using the `ParDo` and `DoFn` in Apache Beam, make some modifications to the record and then update the `GenericRecord`.

Initially I started iterating the GenericArray type of field and then converting each object(GenericRecord) into a JSONObject, since I had to traverse through multiple nestings and update the respective value. I was able to do that, but now I'm struggling to convert the updated JSONObject back into GenericRecord, so that the the whole GenericArray gets updated.

```
val attributes = dataNestedObjGroup.getAsGenericRecord("details")?.get("attributes") as GenericArray<GenericRecord>
attributes.forEach { attribute ->
    val jsonRootObject = JSONObject(attribute.toString())
    jsonRootObject.keySet().forEach { keyStr ->
        val value = jsonRootObject.get(keyStr)
        
        val innerObject = JSONObject(value?.toString())
        val valueOfKey = innerObject.getJSONArray("value")
        if(innerObject.get("name") == "customer_id" && valueOfKey != null){
            // do something
            innerObject.put("value",JsonArray())
        }        
        jsonRootObject.put(keyStr,innerObject)
    }
    // here i have to update the attribute which is a GenericRecord type with the above jsonRootObject (which is a JSONObject type) I've derived above
}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to what we have done in Dataflow Templates.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/v2/common/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/transforms/JsonConverters.java#L160